# Extracting multiple colors from a TextView Android

Tags: java, android, robotium

So I know that to extract a color from the TextView you would use getCurrentTextColor() but my textView contains multiple colors in it. How can I preserve and extract this data? I need the color to do some blackbox testing for my application i.e when a key is pressed, a part of the textview is changed but not all. I'm trying to test if that part is changed so i need to extract that data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably need to do is use `getText()` to retrieve a [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html). You can then extract the `Span`s and for each `Span` get the markup objects associated with it. The markup will usually be classes in [android.text.style](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/package-summary.html): probably [ForegroundColorSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan.html) is what you're looking for.